# SEO Product URLs Not Showing in Anchor Categories on Store View

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, seo, product-urls

I have a lot of categories that are set as anchors for its subcategories. It seems to me that this is easier on the database, rather than having so many rows to crawl through. However, on one of my stores I noticed that products that show up in these categories aren't using SEO-friendly urls unless they are actually in a category, not as an anchor. The cart is set to add category paths to urls. I've checked that my configurations in default and store view are the same. Not exactly sure why SEO product urls work with anchor categories on the main store, but not the store view.

How can the SEO-friendly urls be turned on for products being displayed in an anchor category on a store view?

Comment: If you access them on the anchor level it actually makes sense for me that the URLs only contain the anchor and not more. If you access them on the lower level and the anchor is set to yes then the anchor should be displayed otherwise no

Answer (score 1):

If you access them on the anchor level it actually makes sense for me that the URLs only contain the anchor and not more. If you access them on the lower level and the anchor is set to yes then the anchor should be displayed otherwise no . So from my understanding and knowledge the behaviour of the URLs are correct.